# Using execCommand in Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, wysiwyg

I am trying to create a WYSIWYG editor and I have done:

```
export class WysiwygEditorComponent extends OnInit {
  editor:any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.editor = document.getElementById('editor')
  }
  iBold() {
    this.editor.execCommand('bold', false, null);
  }
}
```

This is the HTML for it:

```
<div>
  <input type="button" (click)="iBold()" value="B">
</div>
<div id='editor' contenteditable>
  <h1>A WYSIWYG Editor.</h1>
  <p>Try making some changes here. Add your own text.</p>
</div>
```

This is my error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at WysiwygEditorComponent.iBold
```

How do I get the html element so I can call `execCommand`, so it can change based on the function that was called?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `execCommand` but based on my limited research, it seems to be a method on the `document`, not the HTML element

Comment: What is the selector for `WysiwygEditorComponent`?

Comment: @snorkpete - Thank you very much. I had made earlier errors and didn't go back to using document but just that one change fixed it. If you put your comment as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as an answer, not as part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `execCommand` is not part of an html object, but the document object, so the error was referring to an HTML element.  The document has to first be in `designMode` and then this function is exposed.

So, this is the problem line:

```
this.editor.execCommand('bold', false, null);
```

changed to

```
document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
```

This solved the problem.

For more information, especially all the commands possible look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) page.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I mean, I know it's your own question, but _for the sake of future generations_ looking at it... ;-) Looks so much better now! Upvoted. Thank *you*!